# Opposite vs. closer regarding the amah-by-amah

Tags: halacha, architecture-design, home-house, bava-batra, zekher-lchurban

The *gemara* in [Bava Batra 60b](http://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.60b.63-64?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) records a *takkana d'rabanan* (Rabbinic enactment) to leave a square cubit unfinished in one's house in commemoration of the destruction of the Temple (codified in the Rambam Hilchoth Ta'anith and Shulkhan Arukh 560:1; see also: http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Volume_7_Issue_8.pdf). The *gemara* further cites that this should be done opposite the entryway.  If the wall immediately facing the front door is all the way across the house, but there is a nearby wall that is a bit to the side, which is the prefered place to make/leave the *zecher l'churban*?
[image: rough diagram of a room in question]

Comment: The most general meaning of "_k'neged_" isn't "opposite". We have practices today "_k'neged_" practices of yore, for example. When it has **physical** meaning, is that always "opposite"? (I don't know. Maybe it is. Do you know?) If not, then on what basis do you say it means "opposite" here?

Comment: @msh210 That use of *k'neged* translates to "corresponding," which is really what opposite means - the corresponding partner on the other side. For physical objects which are generally described as having functional symmetry (front and back, left and right) *k'neged* nearly always means opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The Aruch Hashulchan in [סימן תקס - לעשות זכר לחורבן](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0469_L2) is very explicit:

> ו''כנגד הפתח'' הוא כנגד ממש, כגון אם הפתח במזרח – צריך לעשות דווקא בכותל מערב. ומי שעושה בכותל שהפתח שם, למעלה מהפתח – אינו כלום.‏

He says it has to be directly opposite the front door.

(Right now I can't find it, but I know there's an opinion that says one can put it above the front door.)

Comment: Good find, but that doesn't answer the question fully. OP's talking about using an opposite facing wall, just one that isn't DIRECTLY opposite the door. The Aruch says it needs to be literally *k'neged*, but then contrasts it with using the SAME wall as the door, rather than a wall not directly opposite the opening. It seems this secondary wall might still for his purely directional definition of "opposite."